# To compare two time values which are of the form HH:MM USING SQL

Tags: sql, time, comparison-operators

Is there any simple way to compare two time values using SQL?

For Example, I want to compare like this:-

07:45 >= 04:45

Comment: i suggest they are stored within a varchar column?

Comment: which DBMS you are using?

Comment: this question is not precise enough. You want to compare time values.... but what data type are they? If they are "time" then the answer is self evident. If they are varchar then the question is have they been validated for format and value? If so then a string compare is ok and you save cycles converting a good string to time. If they are varchar and untested then you have to dance to convert and test before comparing the values. THIS IS JUST A BAD QUESTION

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the string values to Time before you do the comparison as shown below:

```
Select * from table where CAST(StartTime As Time) >= CAST(EndTime As Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a time datatype in sql server you can directly use that.

`SELECT CONVERT(TIME,'04:45'+':00')`

Comment: do you have datetime data type in Toad?

Comment: A simple work around to this can be adding date to your time by concatenating it. like say todays date. '2014-06-19' to both of time values you wants to compare. something like cast('2014-06-19'+'04:45'+':00' as Datetime )

Answer (score -1):

As you don't specify a particular DBMS, let's keep it generic. Convert the time values into strings, just as you show them in your question (24hh:mm[.ss]). Any DBMS can do this though the specific methods will differ. Then just compare them. Forced into a zero-padded two char field, the lexical comparison will yield the same result as an arithmetic comparison. That is,

```
Time( '07:45' ) >= Time( '04:45'24 )
```

is equivalent to

```
'07:45' >= '04:45'
```

That being: `true` because the ASCII character '7' is lexically greater than ASCII character '4'.